# Block the user from accessing messaging or completely block incoming/outgoing messages

Tags: java, android, messaging

I am working in java for android, is there any way to completely disable messaging for an android device? Ex: Any time the "loop" returns true the text messaging is disable, no incoming/outgoing are available; or possibly block the user from accessing messaging if returned true?

Comment: I think this question answer is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11201467/2291915

Comment: What loop are you talking about:?

Comment: Thanks, buczek. And I didn't mean to be so generic. As for the loop I should of put maybe a if condition instead in my question.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to completely disable messaging for an android device?

Not really. You could put the device into airplane mode on earlier versions of Android, but fortunately that's now locked down too.

The technique outlined in the link provided in the comment will not be reliable for blocking incoming messaging, as other SMS clients can and do have that priority.